# Error in SQL syntax MySQLSyntaxErrorException in Grails

Tags: mysql, grails

I do request to MySQL database, which searches data in table by criteria:

```
def tableAcounting(){
    def user = Person.findByUsername(springSecurityService.currentUser.username)
    def cafee = user.cafee
    def tablesQuery = TablePlacesInfo.createCriteria()
    def tables = tablesQuery.list {            //AN ERROR SHOW ON THIS STRING
        'in'("hall", HallsZones.findAllByCafee(cafee))
    }
    def halls = cafee.halls
```

But I get such error:

```
Class:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException
Message:You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

Comment: Enable Hibernate SQL logging by adding `logSql = true` into your dataSource definition (`DatataSouce.groovy` file). That should help you seeing the generated queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This usually happends if you do an `in` search using an empty set. This means, that you need to check the size of `HallsZones.findAllByCafee(cafee)` because this set is probably empty.